# Error using LIBSVM, the python binding for SVM library

Tags: python-3.x, libsvm

I'm trying to test the OCR example from the book "Programming Computer Vision with Python" from J.E. Solem (chapter 8.4).

This example uses python bindings for SVM library, LIBSVM.

I'm using **LIBSVM-3.22** (the last one).

I'm getting the following error =>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SVM.py", line 49, in <module>
    prob = svm_problem(labels,features)
  File "/home/pyimagesearch/.virtualenvs/py3cv3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/libsvm/svm.py", line 96, in __init__
    if len(y) != len(x):
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

The code is the following :

```
import os
import svm
import imtools
import imutils
from svmutil import *
from numpy import *
from PIL import Image

def load_ocr_data(path): 
    """ Return labels and ocr features for all images in path. """
    # create list of all files ending in .jpg
    imlist = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(".jpg")]
    # create labels
    labels = [int(imfile.split("/")[-1][0]) for imfile in imlist]
    # create features from the images
    features = []
    for imname in imlist:
        im = array(Image.open(imname).convert("L"))
        features.append(compute_feature(im))
    return array(features),labels

# TRAINING DATA
features,labels = load_ocr_data("./Sudoku/ocr_data/training/")
# TESTING DATA
test_features,test_labels = load_ocr_data("./Sudoku/ocr_data/testing/")

# train a linear SVM classifier
features = map(list,features)
test_features = map(list,test_features)
prob = svm_problem(labels,features)
param = svm_parameter("-t 0")
m = svm_train(prob,param)
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, `map` returns an iterator, so when you do:

```
features = map(list,features)
test_features = map(list,test_features)
```

you are not doing what you thing you are doing.

If you want to convert into a list just do:

```
features = list(features)
test_features = list(test_features)
```

Comment: When I do `features = list(features)`, I have now the following error : `File "SVM.py", line 49, in <module>
    prob = svm_problem(labels,features)
  File "/home/pyimagesearch/.virtualenvs/py3cv3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/libsvm/svm.py", line 103, in __init__
    tmp_xi, tmp_idx = gen_svm_nodearray(xi,isKernel=isKernel)
  File "/home/pyimagesearch/.virtualenvs/py3cv3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/libsvm/svm.py", line 71, in gen_svm_nodearray
    raise TypeError('xi should be a dictionary, list or tuple')
TypeError: xi should be a dictionary, list or tuple`